# ASP.NET MVC - Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to display a textbox depending on the value selected in the Html.DropDownList. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display where?  Show/Hide a textbox depending on value in a drop down?

You could easily achieve this using the change event and jquery.  Something like (untested)

```
$('#dropdownId').change(function(){
  var textbox = $('#textboxId');
  if ($(this).val() == 'foo')
    textbox.hide();
  else
    textbox.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript for that. Add an onchange event for the dropdownlist. Something like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("myList", myData, new { onchange = "showTextBox(this)" }) %>
```

And your myFunc will look along the lines of:

```
function showTextBox(item) {
  if(item.value == 'theCorrectValue')
  {
    document.getElementById('myTextBox').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

If you use jQuery, it'll be slightly easier

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SearchTypeID').change(function () {
    var searchValue = $('#SearchTypeID').val();

    if (searchValue == 4)
    {
        $('#DropdownNames').show();
        $('#TextboxNames').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#TextboxNames').show();
        $('#DropdownNames').hide();
    }

})
```